# Running asp.net app on localhost

Tags: asp.net, iis, localhost

This might be a 'duh' question after all.

Are there any caveats running an asp.net (3.5) application on a local host? Assuming I have all the required services installed, I am looking for pitfalls/ troubles in terms of

- database access
- reporting/ charting and other such features
- performance

The main reason for this is that the app I am developing will be eventually hosted on a proper web server but till then I want to be able to use my app from a browser (for test, demos...).

[Note: till the time the app is hosted on a web server, only I will be using the app]

Answer (score 2):

As long as you install all the same components (and the same versions of them to be 100% sure) on your computer as you have available on the server, there shouldn't be any difference at all in functionality. One thing to watch out for is that the app will certainly be less responsive when someone accesses it over the internet, compared to the client and server being the same machine.

Answer (score 0):

You won't have any problems at all, this is how many people indeed test. When you are ready to move it online, just make sure the host supports everything you need.